# Java Program not outputting the correct value of the equation

Tags: java, eclipse

My code is supposed to take the inputted dew point and temperature data in order to produce the Relative Humidity. For example, a dew point of 46 and a temperature of 100-degrees Fahrenheit will give a relative humidity of around 16. Unfortunately, no matter what your input for these values the answer always comes out to 100.

Here is my code (not finished):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Input the dew point and temperature to get the relative humidity

    System.out.print("Enter dewpoint: ") ;
    // change dewpoint into celcius
    double Td = input.nextDouble() ;
    Td = (5.0 / 9.0) * (Td - 32) ;
    System.out.print("Enter temperature: ") ;
    // change temperature to celcius
    double T = input.nextDouble() ;
    T = (5.0 / 9.0) * (T - 32) ;
    double Rh = 100*(Math.exp((17.625 * Td) / (243.04 + Td)) / Math.exp ((17.625 * T) / (243.04 + T))) ;

    System.out.print("The % Relative Humidity = " +  Rh) ;
}
```

Please help if you can

Comment: Ran it and it worked fine for me: `Enter dewpoint: Enter temperature: The % Relative Humidity = 16.129735479142234`

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider well that's frustrating, I'll test it on a different computer than this one I guess...

Comment: @NEWWIE I can't see any code here that would computer-specfic. You may have just entered the data incorrectly originally.

Comment: I don't think that's going to help you. I'd suggest learning to use the debugger to go step by step to see what's happening. It's probably an issue with your input. Maybe try without the scanner first.

Comment: Ran okay for me too.  What release (version) of Java are you using?

Comment: Notice the last expression.  If either T is set to Td or Td is set to T you're multiplying 100 by 1. It's also possible that T and Td could have been mixed up elsewhere.

Comment: @WJS I fixed it, not sure what happened I just created a new class and copied all data over from the original and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing at all wrong with the way you calculated the humidity.  But as of Java 8 you can use lambda expressions.  These can be use to simplify expressions without resorting to full fledged methods.  It also helps in reducing errors. Here is an example using your code.

```java
      UnaryOperator<Double> toC = f -> 5 / 9. * (f - 32);
      UnaryOperator<Double> fnc = t -> Math.exp((17.625 * t) / (243.04 + t));
      BinaryOperator<Double> humidity =
            (t, td) -> 100 * fnc.apply(td) / fnc.apply(t);

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Input the dew point and temperature to get the relative humidity

      System.out.print("Enter dewpoint: ");
      // change dewpoint into celcius
      double Td = input.nextDouble();
      Td = toC.apply(Td);
      System.out.print("Enter temperature: ");
      // change temperature to celcius
      double T = input.nextDouble();
      T = toC.apply(T);
      double Rh = humidity.apply(T, Td);

      System.out.print("The % Relative Humidity = " + Rh);
```

They can be combined in a variety of ways.  They can also be passed to methods so your passing around a function.  I would recommend you learn them as you as you continue to learn about Java.

Comment: While it's valuable to learn lambdas, I don't see how using them in this case makes sense at all.

Comment: It makes sense when you keep writing the same equations over again.  Less chance of error.  Using lambdas make as much sense as using a method.  Like `Math.abs` for example.  Very simple, but convenient.